# Make Header visible only when its column data is visible SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, header, visibility

I have a table with column headers a, b, c, and d.
With data underneath them of z, y, x, and w respectively.

```
 a   b   c   d
[z] [y] [x] [w]
```

I currently have the data row grouped by z and y with x and w collapsible via z's tablix cell. 
Meaning that the table looks something like this:

Initially before expanding:

```
  a   b   c   d
  z1  y1  
  z2  y2
```

After expanding both rows

```
a   b   c   d
z1  y1  x1 w1
        x2 w2
z2  y2  x3 w3
        x4 w4
        x5 w5
        x6 w6
```

Now here's the problem: Since x and w are collapsible and default to being collapsed. I don't want headers c and d to be visible unless there is at least one x and w data item that is also visible.
After hours of searching I haven't been able to find anything that works for me, so any help would be appreciated.

This link has the closest thing to the solution that I wanted.
This means that before expansion it looks like this:
    a  b
    z1 y1
    z2 y2

And after expansion it looks like this:
    a   b
    z1  y1 
    c   d
    x1 w1
    x2 w2

```
z2 y2
c  d  
x3 w3
x4 w4
x5 w5
x6 w6
```

I hope this helps people!
And thanks for the answers below.

Comment: You can hide the whole column based on a condition. Select the whole column, right click on it and go to Column visibility window. Use this expression to show or hide `IIF(COUNT(Fields!c.Value,"DataSetName")>0,False,True)`. Do the same for the `d` column.

Comment: In this case, c is just a textbox, I can't get the Value of it. Did you mean x? And sorry for being ignorant about SSRS but, what do you mean by "DataSetName"? Would that be c in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating the line group : check the option to add a blanck line.
Then you will have the result you want.

Comment: Adding a blank line will just shift down the non grouped data correct?
I am fine with the way that all of my data is displayed. I just want my headers to change in visibility based on the data in their respective columns. If I misinterpreted your answer let me know, but I am not sure that this will help me. :/

Comment: Yes that's it. You shift down the datas to hide them. I don't think there are other solutions. You can't, simply, manipulate (asking state) visibility properties of elements. Maybe with code but I don't know how :/